# Opening several URLs at once

Tags: windows, plain-text, url

I am looking for a Microsoft Windows program that, given a text as input, can open in my default browser all URLs present in the text (i.e., one URL per tab). Any license or price is fine.

For example, if the text is:

```
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34928/903 : Opening several URLs at once
This is a test https://scholar.google.com/
```

then it should open two tabs in my browser, each containing one URL.

Answer (score 2):

No one has posted a definitive solution, so I'm posting this in hopes that it might help you.

Try [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/) with the [Copy URLs Expert extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/copy-urls-expert/).

How to use:

1. Install Firefox.
2. Load Firefox.
3. Install the Copy URLs Expert extension.
4. Within the extension's options, assign a keyboard shortcut to the "Open URLs from clipboard" function.
5. Copy any block of text, in any application, to the clipboard.
6. Switch to Firefox.
7. Press the keyboard shortcut defined in Step #4 above.
8. Voilà!  All the URLs in your text will open in Firefox.

After Steps 1-4 have been done once, they don't need to be repeated.  Steos 5-7 can be repeated as needed.  You can even write a little macro or script to perform those steps automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any software, but you can use [Linkify](http://soapbox.github.io/linkifyjs/) to identify links in a text.

You enter your text and it "linkifies" it, i.e. finding all the links in the text and makes them clickable. You can then open them in new tabs or any ways you like.